# AVAudioRecorder in iOS 8 does not handle kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

My code worked fine until iOS 8 `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` but now it creates an empty file. No errors are reported. When I changed it to `kAudioFormatLinearPCM` it works. This is my code:

```
recordSettings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin], AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithInt: kAudioFormatLinearPCM], AVFormatIDKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], AVEncoderBitRateKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1], AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:32000.0], AVSampleRateKey,
    nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

Please remove `AVEncoderBitRateKey` key from your settings dictionary and it will work on iOS8 with `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC`.

It could be a specific correlation between `AVEncoderBitRateKey` and `AVNumberOfChannelsKey`. But I didn't play with parameters but used default bitrate value to get working recorder.

Answer (score 3):

That bitrate looks suspiciously low, even for `kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC` (16 bytes per second), maybe try 16000 or 64000 or more.

p.s. try the new Objective-C literals for your `NSDictionarys`, `NSArrays` and `NSNumbers`, I think they're an improvement:

```
recordSettings = @{
    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : AVAudioQualityMin,
    AVFormatIDKey : @(kAudioFormatLinearPCM),
    AVEncoderBitRateKey : @16000,
    AVNumberOfChannelsKey : @1,
    AVSampleRateKey : @32000
};
```

Comment: With kAudioFormatLinearPCM, my AVAudioRecorder is not performing recording.